# Make website remain in desktop view both on mobile view

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want my site to have the exact same desktop view on mobile, any possible solution is okay.To get exactly what I meant, open bithubpay.com on your mobile and desktop, they both got the same view.
I will tag many options because I don't know where the solution will come from

Comment: Use bootstrap css library to achieve the same view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's your larger goal? It seems like this would make the site unusable for mobile devices, which I'm sure is not the result you're aiming for.

While I don't see this being used when I inspect the site, I know you can use the [viewport meta tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag) to control default zooming on websites.